# How To Identify What Element Did User Click in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to know which element did user click.

is there any way to do that?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what exactly you want due to lack of description.

You can try below approach (modify/improve it) to highlight, for instance, clicked button:

```
java_script = """var el = document.querySelectorAll('button'); 
                 for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++)
                 { 
                     el[i].onclick = function()
                     { 
                         this.setAttribute('style', "background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;") 
                     }; 
                 }"""
driver.execute_script(java_script)
```

This will allow you to highlight `button` (change to whatever element type you want) that was clicked.

You can also replace `this.setAttribute('style', "background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;")` with `alert(this.textContent)` to show alert with text of clicked element

Comment: Thanks for reply. is this support non-button elements? I want to know EVERY element user clicked.